# Разбивка сообщения форума

Tags: c#, алгоритм, строки, javascript

Есть сообщение для форума, которое отправил пользователь. Поле для сообщения по ширине и высоте ограничено. Как разбить сообщение так чтобы оно вместилось по ширине в это поле и, если не вмещается по высоте, то поставить многоточие в конце сообщения? Так, чтобы половина слова была на одной строке, а другая половина на второй разбивать НЕЛЬЗЯ.

Реализация на JavaScript и C# желательна.

Comment: высота - количество строк, ширина - количество символов!!!

Answer (score 1):

Для определения места, занимаемого текстом, используйте `Graphics.MeasureString`. А влезает или нет - можно определить, разбив строку на слова и добавляя по одному. Как только слово не влезло - начинаем с него новую строку. Как только не влезло по количеству строк - вместо последнего слова последней строки ставим многоточие. Потом получившеся строки сливаете снова в одну и отображаете полученный абзац.